# "Save Timeline data..." on chrome developer tools produces a 0 bytes file

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to save the timeline data (JSON file) from chrome developer tools while inspecting a chrome page on an android device (Nexus 6). Irrespective of the device I use, saving the timeline data generates a 0 bytes file. This does not happen when saving the timeline of a page launched on the computer.

Should I turn on any of the options in the settings to get this working?

I am not running Chrome in incognito mode on both my computer and android device. I have tried this on google-chrome and chromium-browser.

Comment: Should debug from the chrome side first probably to confirm you can dispatch the info.  We can't say it's an android problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did not use the Dev Channel on android. This helped,
https://www.chromium.org/devtools/capturing-a-timeline-trace